# How can I develop multiple Composer packages at once?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am working on two PHP packages that will be loaded via Composer. I can load Package A using `"type": "path"` and `dev-master` version which creates a symlink to the local version of the package.

However Package B requires a specific version of Package A but if I symlink Package A that means that there is no version that matches the requirements of Package B.

Is there a solution to this? Or are we only able to develop single packages in isolation?

Comment: What you mean is essentially have the same package with different versions both in `vendors` at the same time, using `composer.json`?

Comment: No, I want a single version of each package installed. I want to use my local version of each one, at `dev-master`. Doing this with either package is easy but because one of them requires the other I can't require them both at `dev-master`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving version conflicts is exactly what composer is doing, it seems its opinion is correct.

Is the local path a requirement for you? You could point to a (local) repository, which can be configured in `composer.json` instead of `"type: "path"`.

This is what I have used in the past for local/temporary versions:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@mygitlab.example.com:MyVendor/MyVendorsPackage.git"
      }
    ]
}
```

See docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs